# signalr client hub events not being triggered within a jquery .ready() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I have found that the function within a signalr client hub method is not always triggered when enclosed within a jquery .ready() method. For example this does not always work:

```
$(function(){
hubname.client.methodName = function () {
//do something
}
})
```

whereas the following works reliably:

```
hubname.client.methodName = function () {
    //do something
    }
```

can anyone explain this to me? This pattern of behaviour is not constant, and occurs for me in both chrome and internet explorer.

Comment: Dude I could kiss you. Stumbled upon this after the 100th time attempting to research why my SignalR updates were not working on Chrome (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222128/signalr-updates-not-working-correctly-with-chrome) and this seemingly fixes it. Amazing